# Translating object 2's movement on object 1

Tags: unity, c#

I am moving Object 1 with the translation of the object 2. That is, it should not copy the object 2's position, but instead moving in the same direction/angle as the object 2 is moving. I am stuck at this point where I must add a certain offset if the object is moving Left/Right/Up/Down, since it may be positive/negative floating value. So how do I add an offset to object 1's position?

The problem with the below code is that the object2 comes in position of object1 and then translates which is not what I want.

```
    public Vector3 offsetPosition;

    public Transform Object2;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        offsetPosition = Object2.transform.position - this.transform.position;
        this.transform.position = new Vector3 (Object2.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y, Object2.transform.position.z) - new Vector3 (offsetPosition.x * 0.02f, 0, offsetPosition.z * 0.02f);
    }
```

Comment: Did you mean to cache your offset once in Start(), and then keep using that constant offset every frame in Update() instead of recomputing it?

Comment: Yes exactly. I want to cache ```offsetPosition = Object2.transform.position - this.transform.position;``  only once when the script is active because I am afraid the Object2's position keeps changing.

Comment: So, you tried doing that in the Start() method? What help do you need with this?

Comment: The problem is that Object2 keeps changing.

Comment: What changes Object 2? If you don't show that in your question, then we cannot help you with it.